# php - changing an array order based on another arrays rsort order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has rsort function for a year date as i need them in order from highest to lowest. The variables $variable1,2,3 etc are pre defined from html form date

```
$new_date_year[] = $variable1;
$new_date_year[] = $variable2;
$new_date_year[] = $variable3;

rsort($new_date_year);

$highest_amount = $new_date_year[0];
$second_amount = $new_date_year[1];
$third_amount = $new_date_year[2];
```

the problem I have is that the data that I collated from the html form previous to this isnt being sorted with it. Is there a way that i can sort other arrays directly from the way $new_date_year[] is sorted? As i want the data to be in the same order obviously. array_merge() i have read about but im struggling to apply it in the way I want it to work.

// APPLY `$new_date_year[]` order to this next array..

```
$children_names[] = $first_child_name;
$children_names[] = $second_child_name;
$children_names[] = $third_child_name;
```

So it comes back the same as $new_year_date[] order, like this.

```
$first_child_name = $children_names[0];
$first_child_name = $children_names[1];
$first_child_name = $children_names[2];
```

Basically I need a number of arrays to run off the same order from the original `$new_date_year[]` array which was sorted with rsort so they will follow and match in order together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question!

You can use [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for this:

```
$sortMe = ['A','B','C','D'];
$sortMeToo = ['1','2','3','4'];

array_multisort($sortMe, SORT_DESC, array_keys($sortMe), $sortMeToo);
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/S7JS5).

Further [explaination](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#69656).

There are several other ways to do this. For example you could use [arsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) (which leaves the keys untouched, so they get sorted along the values) and use the sorted keys ([array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)) to build a new sorted array:

```
$sortMe = ['A','B','C','D'];
$sortMeToo = ['1','2','3','4'];

arsort($sortMe);
$sortedKeys = array_keys($sortMe);

$newSortMeToo = [];
foreach ($sortedKeys as $sortedKey) {
    $newSortMeToo[] = $sortMeToo[$sortedKey];
}
$sortMeToo = $newSortMeToo;
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/FHLJl).

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I have looked at the further information you have given me. Can you maybe explain how I can apply it to those more basic variables in my code? Thank you. Jack

Comment: `$sortMe = $new_date_year;` and `$sortMeToo = $children_names;` :)

Comment: Thank you. What if there were 3 ,4 or 5 arrays? :)

Comment: add `array_keys($sortMe), $sortMeToo` for every additional array in `array_multisort` or for second solution add another `$newXYZ = []` and within the loop `$newXYZ[] = $newXYZ[$sortedKey]` - feel free to accept the answer :)